# Export to excel a table with proper file name using jquery in IE and Mozilla both

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written code for exporting the table into excel file in jquery. It is working fine for me but without the proper file name. The file name is some character, digits with % sign.
Here is my code-
function ExportToExcel() {

```
var contents = $(".pvtRendererArea").html();

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
{

    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(contents);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus();
    txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "DataAnalytics.xls");
}
else {

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(contents)); // content is the id of the DIV element  

}
```

}

How to give proper file name can anyone tell me?

Also export to excel in IE for the above code, saving the file in html format with html content. How to write the code for IE so that it will work properly?

here txtArea1 is iframe id which is added in aspx page.

Comment: You cannot force a visitor to use the file name that you suggest when offering a file for download

Comment: I want to give the hardcoded name first then visitor will be asked for the same.